# Property pointing to settings.xml path used

Tags: maven

I have a Maven plugin defined in a pom.xml, to which I want to pass path pointing to settings.xml, which are currently used in a build. Is there a built-in property in Maven I could use for this?

My case:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <container>
            <systemProperties combine.children="append">
                <kie.maven.settings.custom>${looking-for-a-property-to-put-here}</kie.maven.settings.custom>
            </systemProperties>
        </container>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: May I ask what your ultimate goal is? What do you want to read from the settings.xml?

Comment: I don't want to read anything from them. I have a system property that I need to set in a Maven plugin (cargo-maven2-plugin) that points to some settings.xml. And I want this property to be filled with the path pointing to the settings.xml that are used in the build that executes the plugin. Imagine the plugin being a proxy, which passes the path to settings.xml. However I don't know the exact location of the file, because in each run it could be different (set by -s Maven parameter). I want to know if Maven has some built-in property for this.

Comment: I updated the question with the plugin configuration example.

Comment: You can access several properties with `${settings.foo}`, but I do not know a way to get the whole path. You can get the path of the local repository, though.

Comment: Thanks, yes found this, but with this, you access just the settings.xml contents, not it's path. Or at least I didn't find it using ${settings.*}. But I might missed something.

Comment: I googled a lot as well, but it seems that at this time there is no such property available for users.

Comment: @Tibor Zimányi you said: ${settings.foo} works but with this, you access just the settings.xml contents, not it's path. Let me see if I understand: Do you have the settings.xml **absolute path**  to pass it as an argument to your plugin in pom.xml?

Comment: No, I was trying to say that with ${settings.*} I can read content, but I need path.